# NullReferenceException when testing (m == nullptr) with Mathnet Matrix type

Tags: c#, matrix, c++-cli, nullreferenceexception, math.net

I am struggeling with a weird NullReferenceException which occurs when I try to compare an attribute of a type derived from a Matrix type from the [MathNet library](http://www.mathdotnet.com/)  to nullptr.

I want to write a a C++/CLI Class Library with a class Transformation, derived from MathNet::Numerics::LinearAlgebra::Matrix, which should represent Positions in 3D Space as a 4x4 Matrix in homogeneous coordinates. Because I want to be able to set positions relative to other positions i have an attribute `Transformation^ parent`. 
By `if(parent == nullptr){ ... }` I want to test, if the current Transformation has a parent, but I get this Exception in the line with `if(parent == nullptr)`:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MathNet.Iridium.dll 
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

My Transformation class looks like this:

```
/// Transformation.h
using namespace MathNet::Numerics::LinearAlgebra;
using namespace System;
ref class Transformation : Matrix
//ref class Transformation : A
{
public:
    Transformation(void);
    Transformation^ parent;
    void DoSomething();
};


/// Transformation.cpp
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Transformation.h"
Transformation::Transformation(void) : Matrix(4,4)
{
}
void Transformation::DoSomething()
{
    if(parent == nullptr)   // Produces NullReferenceException
    {
        Console::WriteLine("parent is nullptr");
    }
    Matrix^ m;
    if(m == nullptr)        // Produces NullReferenceException, too
    {
        Console::WriteLine("m is nullptr");
    }
}
```

Comparing any variable of Matrix type, that is actually null, to nullptr seems to throw this Exception. If it is initialized properly there is no Exception, so this works fine:

```
Matrix^ m = gcnew Matrix(4,4);
if(m == nullptr)        // works fine
{
    Console::WriteLine("");
}
```

When derive Transformation from a different class, `ref class Transformation : A` instead of `ref class Transformation : Matrix`, everything works fine, too.

And now it gets really weird. I wanted to use my class library in a C#-Application. Calling `t.DoSomething()` on a Transformation t throws the NullReferenceException. BUT, if I include the null-test directly in my C# Application, it works:

```
Transformation t = new Transformation();
// t.DoSomething();      // Throws NullReferenceException
if (t.parent == null)    // OK!
{
    Console.WriteLine("parent is null");
}
```

Doing the same in a C++/ClI application again throws the NullReferenceException:

```
Transformation^ t = gcnew Transformation();
// t->DoSomething();     // Throws NullReferenceException
if(t->parent == nullptr) // Throws NullReferenceException
{
    Console::WriteLine("parent is nullptr");
}
```

Any suggestions where this might come from? I am really quite puzzled...

I use the [MathNet.Idirium Library, Version 2008.8.16.470](http://www.mathdotnet.com/downloads/Iridium-2008-8-16-470.ashx)

Comment: This normally indicates that *this* is null.  Doesn't match your test code though.  Maybe a versioning problem.

Comment: If this (meaning t in this context) were null, I couldn't call DoSomething() on t or am I wrong? The Exception is thrown only inside DoSomething(), not when it is called.

Comment: It is different for C++/CLI, it doesn't generate code to ensure that *this* is not null like C# does.  It bombs later when you try to access a class member.  Can be hard to diagnose.  But I agree that your tests make it very unlikely that this is the real cause of the problem.  Look at *this* in the debugger for any kind of hint.

Comment: I can inspect "this" in the Debugger (doesn't point to "<undefined value>") and also its nested attribute of type Matrix has been initialized correctly. Only parent points to "<undefined value>".

Because the problem also occurs with local variables (see class definition above, Matrix^ m) I guess it might not be a problem with "this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible in C# at least for the == operator to be implemented in a way that throws a null reference.

Can you try calling Object::ReferenceEquals(obj, null) and see if that works or not?

Comment: Thank you Andy, comparing with `if(Object::ReferenceEquals(parent, nullptr))` passes without an Excception!

So this is a subtlety in the implementation of Matrix?

Comment: @richn : If by 'subtlety' you mean 'bug' then yes.

Comment: @ildjarn Haha ;-) I just wanted to know if I could "see" when to use `ReferenceEquals()` and when `==`.

Comment: @richn:  The only way to "see" would be if you can look at the source code for Matrix and look at the operator== implementation.  So if you don't have it and can't decompile it, you maybe out of luck.  Its most certainly a bug in that code though, as Equals, GetHashCode and operator implemenations must NEVER throw exceptions, according to MSDN documentation.

Comment: @Andy MathNet is open source, and after a quick look into the implementation of Matrix I couldn't find any implementation of the == operator. But never mind, I will go with your fix for now and search for the reason why `==` doens't work when I have more time. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @richn I'm not sure then.  I know C#, I must admit that managed C++ isn't something I've worked with.  I assumed if == wasn't defined for that type you'd get a compile error, but apparently not!